# Can I copy and amend a coded ui test?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

My situation.

We have a Dev and Staging environment. I already have coded ui tests running within a solution for my Dev environment and they work perfectly. Is it possible to copy these tests, amend the website it goes to (can do it in the code - BrowserWindow Launch) and run them in a different solution? I tried and as soon as I change it in the new solution, it changes the original test. Both environments have the exact same functionality.

This would save me a lot of time, if it is possible.

Cheers
Russ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute Coded UI Tests in multiple environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239523/execute-coded-ui-tests-in-multiple-environments)

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239523/execute-coded-ui-tests-in-multiple-environments).

Other questions with related ideas include [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041376/how-can-i-run-the-same-coded-ui-test-with-multiple-input-files) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27047119/how-to-run-mtm-tests-on-multiple-product-builds).